# Pivot with dynamic DATE columns

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a query that I created from a table.

example:

```
select
        pkey,
        trunc (createdformat) business_date,
        regexp_substr (statistics, 'business_ \ w *') business_statistics
    from business_data
    where statistics like '% business_%'
    group by regexp_substr(statistics, 'business_\w*'), trunc(createdformat)
```

This works great thanks to your help.
Now I want to show that in a crosstab / pivot.

That means in the first column are the "business_statistics", the column headings are the "dynamic days from business_date".
I've tried the following, but it doesn't quite work yet

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM (
        select
          pkey,
          trunc(createdformat) business_date,
          regexp_substr(statistics, 'business_\w*') business_statistics
         from business_data
         where statistics like '%business_%'
            )
       PIVOT(
         count(pkey)
         FOR business_date
         IN ('17.06.2020','18.06.2020')
        )
     ORDER BY business_statistics
```

If I specify the date, like here 17.06.2020 and 18.06.2020 it works. 3 columns (Business_Statistic, 17.06.2020, 18.06.2020). But from column 2 it should be dynamic. That means he should show me the days (date) that are also included in the query / table. So that is the result of X columns (Business_Statistics, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, ....). Dynamic based on the table data.

For example, this does not work:

...
IN (SELECT DISTINCT trunc(createdformat) FROM BUSINESS_DATA WHERE statistics like '%business_%' order by trunc(createdformat))
...

Answer (score 0):

The pivot clause doesn't work with dynamic values.

But there are some workarounds discuss here: [How to Convert Rows to Columns and Back Again with SQL (Aka PIVOT and UNPIVOT)](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot) 
You may find one workaround that suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with PL / SQL. But could I still process the start date and the end date of the user for the query?

For example, the user enters the APEX environment as StartDate: June 17, 2020 and as EndDate: June 20, 2020.

Then the daily difference is calculated in the PL / SQL query, then a variable is filled with the value of the entered period using Loop.

Example: (Just an idea, I'm not that fit in PL / SQL yet)

```
DECLARE
startdate := :P9999_StartDate 'Example 17.06.2020
enddate := P9999_EndDate 'Example 20.06.2020
BEGIN
   LOOP 'From the startdate to the enddate day
     businessdate := businessdate .... 'Example: 17.06.2020,18.06.2020,19.06.2020, ...
   END LOOP

    SELECT * 
      FROM (
        select
          pkey,
          trunc(createdformat) business_date,
          regexp_substr(statistics, 'business_\w*') business_statistics
         from business_data
         where statistics like '%business_%'
            )
       PIVOT(
         count(pkey)
         FOR business_date
         IN (businessdate)
        )
     ORDER BY business_statistics
END;
```

That would be my idea, but I fail to implement it. Is that possible? I hope you understand what I mean